# submit form after creating new user

Tags: javascript

I am using Sinch SDK for my application. This is the JavaScript code to create users using sinch:

```
var signUpObj = {};
  signUpObj.username = $('input#username').val();
  signUpObj.password = $('input#username').val(); 

sinchClient.newUser(signUpObj);
```

This code is working perfectly. What i want is once the new user is created, then this code will execute :

```
$("#myForm").submit();
```

How can i achieve this using JavaScript? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: add `$("#myForm").submit();` after this code

Comment: Do you mean to call it after newUser, then you can use it as a callback like `sinchClient.newUser(signUpObj, function() {$("#myForm").submit();
});`

Comment: @JaromandaX after what code? i tried placing it after the  `sinchClient.newUser(signUpObj);` . the data is saving to my database but it is not saving to the SDK.

Comment: Forgive me but your given code is NOT running perfectly `signUpObj.password = $('input#username').val();` see the issue here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks Aswin Ramesh. your solution worked!

Solution:

```
sinchClient.newUser(signUpObj, function() {$("#myForm").submit(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
sinchClient.newUser(signUpObj)
    .then(function() {
        //Things to do on success
       $("#myForm").submit();
    })
    .fail(function(error) {
        //Manage error (One/more identities may be taken, or password not strong enough, or other)
    })
```

Documentation: http://download.sinch.com/docs/javascript/latest/reference/classes/SinchClient.html